# Mocha + RequireJS = AMD testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, mocha.js, js-amd

I have a hard time connecting Mocha to RequireJS based application, may be You'll be able to come up with something :). After many hours when I've been trying to load AMD modules and simply console.log some 'fired' info that the module has been loaded... nothing happend had happened - the program just ended and printed out some mocha info.

```
var facade = requirejs(['../../public/js/scripts/widgets/widgets/article/main.js'],      
    function(mod) {
        console.log('fired')
});
// run with: $ mocha -u tdd test.js --reporter spec
```

and than I've come up with the idea to fire just this to test callbacks:

```
setTimeout((function() {
    console.log('fired');
}), 5000);
// run with: $ mocha -u tdd test.js --reporter spec
```

also didn't work. So finally I've run both with

```
$ node test.js
```

and finally it worked. So question is than: **How to run Mocha test with callbacks handling, as those are essential for AMD testing?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The way you are doing it, mocha is not going to do anything with your file because it does not see *a test suite* in it. RequireJS is scheduled to call the callback but mocha exits before this has a chance to happen. Same with your timeout example.

The following gives you an example.

File `test.js`:

```
'use strict';
var requirejs = require("requirejs");
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '.',
    nodeRequire: require
});

suite('Something', function(){
    var foo;

    suiteSetup(function (done){
        // This saves the module foo for use in tests. You have to use
        // the done callback because this is asynchronous.
        requirejs(['foo'],
                  function(mod) {
            console.log("fired!");
            foo = mod;
            done();
        });
    });

  suite('blah', function(){
    test('blah', function(){
      if (foo.test !==  "test")
          throw new Error("failed!");
    });
  });
});
```

File `foo.js`:

```
define(function () {
   return {test: "test"};
});
```

When you run:

```
mocha -u tdd test.js
```

You'll see that the callback is fired and the test passes.

For the benefit of people reading this question and confused by the use of `suite`, `suiteSetup`, `test`... Mocha supports multiple interfaces. The code here is using the TDD interface (the OP invokes Mocha with `-u tdd`), which exports `suite`, `suiteSetup`, `test`, etc. In the default BDD interface, the equivalents are `describe`, `before` and `it`, respectively.

Comment: Not just ``done``, see the paragraph I added to the start of the answer. Mocha did not see a test suite in the file and exited right away.

Answer (score 4):

I have configured related boilerplate for using mocha in environment of RequireJS. It may be not exact what you want, but it may be helpful.
https://github.com/x2es/boilerplate-karma-mocha-chai-requirejs

One more note - assuming that your script placed in "/public" it makes sense to test it in browser environment instead nodejs. For this purposes you should to look at some test-runner like JsTestDriver (https://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/) or karma-runner (http://karma-runner.github.io/). Or another...

In snipped provided in karma documentation (http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html)

```
var tests = [];
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
  if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
    if (/Spec\.js$/.test(file)) {
      tests.push(file);
    }
  }
}

requirejs.config({
    // Karma serves files from '/base'
    baseUrl: '/base/src',

    paths: {
        'jquery': '../lib/jquery',
        'underscore': '../lib/underscore',
    },

    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        }
    },

    // ask Require.js to load these files (all our tests)
    deps: tests,

    // start test run, once Require.js is done
    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

introduced way when we force requirejs to preload all necessary spec-files using

```
require.config({
  deps: ['array', 'of', 'our', 'spec', 'files']
})
```

In this environment each spec-file should be a regular RequireJS module.

Example of test spec for such environment:

```
define(['chai'], function(chai) {
  var expect = chai.expect;

  describe('bootstrap', function() {
    it('should...', function() {
      expect('a').to.equal('a');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I think this solution is also ok but it uses 'chai' and I want to handle it without 'promises' for now. But thank You for the effort :).