# Getting chai to play nice with requirejs

Tags: requirejs, mocha.js, karma-runner, chai, requirejs-text

I am attempting to set up Karma/Mocha/Chai into my Backbone project, which uses requirejs and not having much luck.

First, here's my setup:

```
- app/
  - js/
- bower_components/
- node_modules/
- test/
  - test-main.js
- karma.conf.js


// relevant bits of karma.conf.js
frameworks: ['mocha', 'requirejs', 'chai'],
files: [
    'test/test-main.js',
    {pattern: 'bower_components/requirejs-text/text.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'bower_components/underscore/underscore.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'bower_components/backbone/backbone.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'app/js/**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'test/**/*Spec.js', included: falase}
],
exclude: [ 'app/js/requireConfig.js', 'app/js/main.js' ],
preprocessors: { '**/*.html': [] },


// test-main.js
var allTestFiles = [];
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$\i;
var pathToModules = function(path) {
    return path.replace(/^\/base\//, '').replace(/\.js$/, '');
}
Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
    if (TEST_REGEXP.text(file)) {
        allTestFiles.push(pathToModule(file));
    }
});

require.config({
    baseUrl: '/base/app/js',
    paths: {
        text: '../../bower_components/requirejs-text/text',
        jquery: '../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
        underscore: '../../bower_components/underscore/underscore',
        backbone: '../../bower_components/backbone/backbone',
        test: '../../test',
    },
    deps: allTestFiles,
    callback: window.__karma__.start;
});
```

---

When I run karma, I get:

> Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(module) {
>   --the entire contents of text.js --

I tried changing the order of "frameworks" to `frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', requirejs']`, which made the mismatch error go away, but then got:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'window.chai.should')

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/xdissent/karma-chai/issues/5) and the recommendation is to keep *requirejs* before *chai*.

Does anyone have experience getting requirejs-text to work? Thanks.

Comment: See this topic for usage requirejs with mocha:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473614/mocha-requirejs-amd-testing/20474031#20474031

Answer (score 1):

Welp, sorry to waste a question on SO. I started from scratch and my above configuration (aside from needing "{pattern: 'app/js/**/*.html', included: false}") worked fine.

For completeness, here is the updated configuration:

```
- app/
  - js/
- bower_components/
- node_modules/
- test/
  - test-main.js
- karma.conf.js


// ---- relevant bits of karma.conf.js ----

// "requirejs" must come before "chai" or Chai will not load properly.
// Sidenote: Karma loads the listed frameworks backwards.
frameworks: ['mocha', 'requirejs', 'chai'],

// Contrary to what a few stackoverflow and github issue responses
// suggested, the order of files do not appear to matter at all.
files: [
  'test/test-main.js',

  // app files
  {pattern: 'app/js/**/*.html', included: false},
  {pattern: 'app/js/**/*.js', included: false},

  // tests
  {pattern: 'test/**/*Spec.js', included: false},

  // libraries
  {pattern: 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js', included:false, watching: false},
  {pattern: 'bower_components/underscore/underscore.js', included:false, watching: false},
  {pattern: 'bower_components/backbone/backbone.js', included:false, watching: false},
  {pattern: 'bower_components/requirejs-text/text.js', included:false, watching: false},
],

exclude: [ 'app/js/requireConfig.js', 'app/js/main.js' ],

preprocessors: {},


// ---- test-main.js ----
var allTestFiles = [];
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
    if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
        if (/Spec\.js$/.test(file)) {
            allTestFiles.push(file);
        }
    }
}

require.config({
    baseUrl: '/base/app/js',
    paths: {
        jquery: '../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
        underscore: '../../bower_components/underscore/underscore',
        backbone: '../../bower_components/backbone/backbone',
        text: '../../bower_components/requirejs-text/text',
    },
    deps: allTestFiles,
    callback: window.__karma__.start;
});
```

Comment: how does your package.json look like?